# ¿Cómo debo hacer para imprimir una lista de manera vertical?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(24):
    D=random.randint(1,54)
    X=D*Micros[i]
    Pasajeros.append(X)
```

¿Cómo debo imprimirlo de manera vertical?

Comment: Te refieres a algo así: `print("\n".join(Pasajeros))`?

Comment: Cuenta la leyenda que si se imprime eso vertical puede leerse cuál es la pregunta

Comment: No podemos saber cómo debes hacerlo. Se supone que eso lo sabes tú. Si todavía sigues activo deja un ejemplo de cómo debería verse la salida del programa.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías agregar un poco más del código para estar en contexto con lo que quieres hacer, infiriendo un poco en lo que pretendes puedes mostrar cada elemento de la lista recorriendola con un for e imprimes cada elemento:

```
import random
Pasajeros = list()
for i in range(24):
    D=random.randint(1,54)
    Pasajeros.append(D)

print(Pasajeros) #Imprime todo la lista

for pasajero in Pasajeros: #Imprime cada elemento de la lista
    print(pasajero)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Usando `join` + `print`:

Usa el método `join` de la clase `str` para convertir la lista en una cadena. Como separador, usa "\n" para que al unir la lista, entre cada 2 elementos, aparezca un salto de línea.

Ten en cuenta que los elementos del iterable deben ser de tipo `str`, así que, en tu caso, primero tendrías que hacer un *"casting"*:

```
Pasajeros : list[str] = [str(p) for p in Pasajeros]

Pasajeros_str : str = '\n'.join(Pasajeros)
print(Pasajeros_str)
```

---

### Usando únicamente `print`:

Pásale a `print` directamente la secuencia desempaquetada, y haz uso del parámetro `sep` para que, en vez de un espacio en blanco (valor por defecto), se separen los elementos con un salto de línea:

```
print(*Pasajeros, sep='\n')
```

---

### Referencias:

- [str.join()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/join.html)
- [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Answer (score 0):

Para imprimir asi:

```
"
1
2
3
4
"
```

Basta con porner un \n

```
output = ""
for p in pasajeros:
    output = output + str(p) + "\n"

print(output)
```

Comment: puedes usar *f-strings* `output += f"{p}\n"` y el `for` se puede eliminar y usar el método `.join()` de los strings